Rank and local frame for the tautological line bundle over the Real projective space
Considering  the standard atlas
$(U_0, \phi_0), \ldots, (U_n, \phi_n)$ that is used to describe the smooth structure on $\mathbb{P}^n$.
and the tautological line bundle
$$ E := \{(l, v) \in \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : v \in l \}, $$
with the projection $\pi : E \to M, \, \pi(l, v) = l$, and with the vector space structure on its fibers given by
$$ (l, v) + (l, w) = (l, v + w), \quad \text{etc.} $$
1 What is the rank of $E$? From the definition of $E$, il looks like $v\in  \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ implies that the dimension of the fibers are n+1, which would then be the rank of the vector bundle.
But on the other hand each fiber consist of vectors lying on the line l, and a line is one-dimensional, then the rank is 1? Can someone clear this up? Is it 1 or n+1?
2 I want to define a  nowhere vanishing local section $s_i$ of $E$
defined over $U_i$ and exibit a (local) frame of E
The projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ can be covered by $n + 1$ standard open sets $U_i$ defined as
$$ U_i = \{ [x_0 : \cdots : x_n] \in \mathbb{P}^n : x_i \neq 0 \}, $$
Since each $ U_i $ can be equipped with local coordinates (called affine coordinates) using the map: $\phi_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ [x_0 : \cdots : x_n] \mapsto \left( \frac{x_0}{x_i}, \ldots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{x_i} \right). $$
and this  gives a smooth atlas for $ \mathbb{P}^n $ consisting of $ (U_i, \phi_i) $ for $ i = 0, \ldots, n $, I have defined therefore the section as:
$s_i(l) = \left( l, \left( \frac{x_0}{x_i}, \ldots, 1, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{x_i} \right) \right)$
what would be then a local frame ?

It is actually rank 1 since each fiber is 1-dimensional. Every fiber of $l$ (as a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$) is actually $l$ itself (as a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$)
